# What is the simmering temperature in thermometer?

Tags: temperature

I would like to know the simmering temperature what is when we simmering food.

I just purchased a food thermometer and would like to learn how to use it.

Comment: A quick google search yeilded, "Simmering is a food preparation technique in which foods are cooked in hot liquids kept just below the boiling point of water (which is 100 °C or 212 °F at average sea level air pressure), but higher than poaching temperature (higher than 71–82 °C or 160-180°F)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exact temperature, but consensus is that the temperature needs to be below the boiling point of 100 °C / 212 °F and above the poaching temperature of 82 °C / 180 °F.